# Unzipping Multiple Files - Java

Tags: java, caching, zip

I'm working on an auto updater for a game client and I've run into an issue.

What I need it to do: Download cache.zip and client.zip. Extract cache.zip to cacheDir and extract client.zip to the same location they are running the jar(game).

What it does right now: Downloads both cache.zip and client.zip. Extracts cache.zip to the correct location, but also to the location the jar is at. It doesn't extract client.zip at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use this function to unzip a file:

```
public static void unzip(final ZipFile source, final File destination) throws IOException {
    for (final ZipEntry entry : Collections.list(source.entries())) {
        unzip(source, entry, destination);
    }
}

private static void unzip(final ZipFile source, final ZipEntry entry, final File destination) throws IOException {
    if (!entry.isDirectory()) {
        final File resource = new File(destination, entry.getName());
        if (!resource.getCanonicalPath().startsWith(destination.getCanonicalPath() + File.separator)) {
            throw new IOException("Entry is outside of the target dir: " + entry);
        }

        final File folder = resource.getParentFile();
        if (!folder.exists()) {
            if (!folder.mkdirs()) {
                throw new IOException();
            }
        }

        try (final BufferedInputStream input = new BufferedInputStream(source.getInputStream(entry));
             final BufferedOutputStream output = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(resource))) {
            output.write(input.readAllBytes());
            output.flush();
        }
    }
}
```

Here are some overload:

```
public static void unzip(final String file) throws IOException {
    final File source = new File(file);
    unzip(
            new ZipFile(source),
            new File(source.getParent(), source.getName().substring(0, source.getName().lastIndexOf('.')))
    );
}

public static void unzip(final String source, final String destination) throws IOException {
    unzip(new File(source), new File(destination));
}

public static void unzip(final File source, final File destination) throws IOException {
    unzip(new ZipFile(source), destination);
}
```

Note:

- It ignore the empty directories. You can add an else and mkdir the entries if you need them.
- If you need to speedup the process, you can add a threadpool on `unzip(final ZipFile source, final File destination)` for calling `unzip(final ZipFile source, final ZipEntry entry, final File destination)` with multiple threads.
- `unzip(final ZipFile source, final ZipEntry entry, final File destination)` is checking for each entry if the canonical path of the output start by the canonical path of the destination to avoid `Zip Slip Vulnerability` - See https://snyk.io/research/zip-slip-vulnerability - but you may ignore this check for you use case.

And if you need to get your jar repertory:

```
String fileRepertory = Setup.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().toURI().getPath();
```

And finally, if you need to zip a file (I post it here as a backup for myself ^^')

```
public static void zip(final File destination, final List<File> toZip) throws IOException {
    try (final ZipOutputStream zip = new ZipOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(destination))) {
        for (final File file : toZip) {
            final ZipEntry entry = new ZipEntry(file.getCanonicalPath());
            zip.putNextEntry(entry);
            zip.write(Files.readAllBytes(file.toPath()));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I was able to base my unzip off that and fix my problem! You the bomb!

Comment: `readAllBytes` isn't great, better to use `input.transferTo(output)`.